# Problem with Oracle BI Delevery Mail?

Tags: oracle10g

Ahter configuring Email in Bi publisher as
"

> SMTP NAME:- SMTP.GMAIL.COM, HOST NAME:- SMTP.GMAIL.COM, UserName:-bhuvan.ram@gmail.com,Password=XXXXX
>
> Then in the Delivery Configuration ,Email From Address :- bhuvan.ram@gmail.com and Email To Address :- bhuvan.ram@xxxxx.com

But when i click on send Report I am getting the Following Message

> oracle.apps.xdo.service.delivery.DeliveryException: oracle.apps.xdo.delivery.DeliveryException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q2sm1535290pbj.35

```
at oracle.apps.xdo.service.delivery.impl.DeliveryServiceImpl.deliverToEmail(DeliveryServiceImpl.java:228)
at oracle.apps.xdo.servlet.scheduler.XDOJob.deliver(XDOJob.java:1190)
at oracle.apps.xdo.servlet.scheduler.XDOJob.execute(XDOJob.java:478)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

Caused by: oracle.apps.xdo.delivery.DeliveryException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q2sm1535290pbj.35

```
at oracle.apps.xdo.delivery.smtp.SMTPDeliveryRequestHandler.submitRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.xdo.delivery.AbstractDeliveryRequest.submit(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.xdo.service.delivery.impl.DeliveryServiceImpl.deliverToEmail(DeliveryServiceImpl.java:222)
... 4 more
```

Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q2sm1535290pbj.35

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1020)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:716)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:388)
```

How to solve the above scenario

Regards
Bhuvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this. This may help others: Oracle BI doesnt supports TLS (Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail)